# Magento 2 Component Showing on checkout but in wrong place

Tags: magento, magento2

Background: Magento 2.1.7. Custom theme overriding default Luma theme.

I've got a custom component working and displaying on the checkout page but I'm struggling to get it to show where I want it.

I've called it 'my-component' and replaced the actual vendor with 'Vendor' below but I've written the associated js and html and **the component works exactly as expected**. The only issue is I'm trying to get it to render directly underneath the shipping form, so I think this is a layout issue?

My module currently just outputs the text 'Test' in a div and I'm trying to add my component to the children of 'item name="address-list-additional-addresses"'. I don't know if this is the right place but I'm just trying to get it after the form.

Currently it outputs directly above the shipping address form in an li with an id of "custom-field" which is not part of my .html template and I'm not knowingly adding. I can't find any way to add it after this shipping address form which is what I want.

I know my changes to checkout_index_index.xml are working as I can move my component to 'item name="before-shipping-method-form"' and it ends up above the shipping method form as you'd expect.

**my-component.html** (gets pulled in above shipping form inside li id="custom-field")

```
<div class="cart-tc-notice">
    Test
</div>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml** (my theme's version and works - I can target other things in the default checkout_index_index.xml and it takes effect and moves my component around)

```
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="address-list-additional-addresses" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="my-component" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor/js/view/checkout/my-component</item>
                                                            </item>
```

I guess if I was dealing with containers or blocks, I'd just do a cheeky after="-"... Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add your component after "before-form" instead of "address-list-additional-addresses"

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, it still rendered above the form. Thankfully the requirement has been dropped now anyway, but thanks for answering.